# Rails Assets in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, production-environment

I've just migrated to rails 3.1 and I'm having trouble getting started with the asset pipeline.

I ran: `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` after adding additional css files into `config.assets.precompile += ['scaffold.css', 'other.css', 'other.js']` all of my files are located in the `/app/asset` images, javascripts, or stylesheets path.

Following the rake task, I can see the manifest.yml file but it is missing the additional css and js files I added to the     `config.assets.precompile`

Here is my manifest.yml file that lives on prod:

> connect.gif: connect-b85d46914c10cb653f3444c3529b83eb.gif connect.png:
>   connect-bce549a396f27cc5f7b315190ee3385a.png d.jpeg:
>   d-c5f2ca3025794efdc341159538f4a0bf.jpeg data.png:
>   data-d225a9937a1aa78805e704ada167b2d0.png fb.png:
>   fb-2e743f3607323f9d21dd2e96b5c95d4b.png feed.png:
>   feed-fd4c0dc513639edd0ba2f39a063fdc90.png grid.png:
>   grid-b3db76abb46477b06c15055df8412c79.png i.png:
>   i-5ac52498083d9dfc5f898cdf666bc9c0.png infb.png:
>   infb-80208a4e1bd3d2a03f23097a7d19fe7e.png r.png:
>   r-ba27ded8b8873c851cd9aaf8697f8092.png rails.png:
>   rails-e4b51606cd77fda2615e7439907bfc92.png share.jpeg:
>   share-47877a532c58510f38eeb534122b4846.jpeg share.png:
>   share-b9939bdcdf8b082eeb27697592258b9a.png signup.jpeg:
>   signup-23dfea4e8af95dae93ab254162e01fc2.jpeg tc.png:
>   tc-abb1838a7396c3a0a54e68ecb80cd225.png tweet.png:
>   tweet-3865676af138fa7d80e0e416210f2fa0.png yellow.png:
>   yellow-b2257e0f9bb17cd4b44faaee30df8fa6.png jquery.flot.js:
>   jquery.flot-944582c3d888856c9d82964ea8cf0bcc.js jquery-ui.min.js:
>   jquery-ui.min-4258e47b40673a02bedfda178628bfba.js jquery.min.js:
>   jquery.min-17322428695737103f15e8b9db8b5909.js application.js:
>   application-f71535809bb0483163e3e4d857abe6d0.js

What is going on here? I've restarted both passenger with touch restart.txt and nginx. I've read all of the documentation on this issue.

**nginx error.log:**

```
cache: [GET /] miss

ActionView::Template::Error (scaffold.css isn't precompiled):
    2: %html
    3:   %head
    4:     %title redmeetsblue
    5:     
    6:     = javascript_include_tag "application.js"
    7:     = csrf_meta_tag
    8:     %script{:src => "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=143150285757259&xfbml=1"}
  app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_haml__44133251_81438200'
  app/controllers/homes_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the config.assets.precompile values in application.rb ? If you set them elsewhere they won't be picked up when you precompile.